# how to get previous month first day and future month last day using moment.js

Tags: momentjs

how to get previous month first day and future month last day using moment.js,Please guide me with the relevant script required to achieve this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service

Comment: Could you provide us with the code you have tried so far, and where you are getting hung up?

Answer (score 24):

try something like

`var prevMonthFirstDay = new moment().subtract(1, 'months').date(1)`

and

```
var nextMonthLastDay = new moment().add(2, 'months').date(0)
```

Answer (score 19):

or more verbose:

```
prevMonthFirstDay : moment().subtract(1, 'months').startOf('month')

nextMonthLastDay: moment().add(1, 'months').endOf('month')
```

Comment: This answer is better cause it reset the time to 0:00:00, which is easier to compare between dates.